# How can we open Amazon Alexa app from our ionic app?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic3, alexa-skills-kit

I want to open Amazon Alexa app from my ionic app? Implement the Alexa app flow as the primary flow, and the LWA flow as a fallback for when the Alexa app isn't installed.

Answer (score 0):

Import these into your .ts file:

```
import { Plugins, AppState } from '@capacitor/core';
const { App } = Plugins;
```

Get App ID of the destination application (e.g. 'com.facebook.katana'), and launch it like so:

```
async launchApp(){
  if (await App.canOpenUrl({ url: 'com.facebook.katana' }))
      await App.openUrl({ url:’com.facebook.katana' });
}
```

More info here: https://javascript.plainenglish.io/opening-another-app-from-your-ionic-5-app-becf8c098d0e